# StopWatch causing error in attribute value

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a Projectile class and I have some fields in it like initialVelocity, currentVelocity and so on (Velocity and Acceleration are composed - they themselves are classes having X and Y components which are of double datatype)

I am facing a very strange error that as long as Stop Watch is running, I get correct value of *InitialVelocity*, but once StopWatch stops, it gives me a wrong value of *InitialVelocity*.

Remember that I have not made any setter of *initialVelocity*, neither it's value is being changed in class once I assign it starting value of velocity in constructor. I have checked again and again and there is not a single line over-writing the value of *initialVelocity*, so why is it happening?

Comment: InitialVelocity and currentVelocity are the same object. If you change one you change the other.

Comment: But once I assign that object to initialVelocity and currentVelocity, there isn't link left b/w them anymore.

Comment: Your code is not complete so it's hard to understand what happens, you didn't show how you use the stopwatch. It seems that you just start it

Comment: It just starts in constructor and nothing else has been done on it. As I shown in question, I am getting Stop Watch's elapsed time for CurrentTimeInAir only. And I am stoping Stop Watch manually in the main() code (after total time of flight).

Comment: Something is missing. You should show all of your relevant code

Comment: Another couple of questions: what are the expected values in your opinion? Did you update current velocity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72509/discussion-between-talha-irfan-and-davide-lettieri).

Comment: I'm assuming that you removed your code now that the question was answered because of some concern over it's content.  However, please bear in mind, the previous edits are still visible, so your code is still accessible, and by removing the code, you make the question less applicable to others who may have similar issues.

Comment: @Claies Unfortunately yes I also knew it once I had shared the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current velocity and initial velocity are the same object. When you change one you change the other.

In your constructor you have to create two different instance of velocity for the two properties

Comment: Perfect!! Can't tell you how much annoying it was. Thank you so much. You saved my day('s hard work)

Comment: I hope you understand your mistake!